# How to remove margin left of different type of containers using xslt or css

Tags: css, xslt-1.0, containers, image-gallery

-I generating image gallery that suports different types of containers. ie 33% container,50%container and 100 % container. 
-if container is of type 33% percent then three containers will come in one row separated by verticle line and margin. I want to remove left margin of first container and right margin last container.
-if container is of type 50% percent then two containers will come in one row separated by verticle line and margin. I want to remove left margin of first container and right margin other container. 
-if container is of type 100% percent then only one container is there and no need to remove margin.

- Issue is that when multiple containers of this types are present in image gallery in any sequence  then how predict which containers rignt margin and line separator has to remove. how to do this?

Comment: can you provide code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the css pseudoselectors :firstchild and :lastchild to style your divs.